# Is it necessary to reboot after defragmenting an external drive when using Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, defragment

It's my understanding from many years ago, that it is imperative to reboot after defragmenting .  Is this still true for an external drive?  I'm guessing that this would hold true for another partition as well, i.e., a data partition.  Thank you for your time to anyone answering.

Comment: Why would it be imperative to reboot after defragmenting?!

Comment: The only reason that I can think of for rebooting after defragmenting would be to reset the next-free-cluster pointer so that the next write is at the start of the free block instead of somewhere in the middle/end.

Comment: Is this even relevant on a data drive? Won't `chkdsk` do the same thing? Or is it related to forcing `chkdsk` to run at reboot?

Comment: Yes it is relevant. I just performed a defrag to free up a large chuck of free space, but if I then create a folder, instead of the folder being created at the beginning of the free block, it is created in the middle, thus breaking the large free block into two chunks (which of course could drastically increases the chances of future fragmentation). `chkdsk` has no effect on the *next-free-cluster* pointer. I’m looking for a way to force the drive/OS to reset the pointer, but so far, rebooting seems to be the only effective solution.